# Pentaho Report Designer Templates stopped working

Tags: java, templates, report, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

A few days ago the Reporting Wizard stopped working.
If I try to use it, I can select a template and pick a datasource, but it won't allow me to go any further.
I'm using the Pentaho Report Designer 5.3 and mysql / JDBC.

My operating system is Windows 7. Anyone got a tip on how to get it going again?

Here is what I tried so far:

- Templates work on other PC's
- Datasource and Query should be fine, since I get the results in the Preview
- Deleted the .Pentaho folder and the Report Designer, and downloaded it again
- checked the Java_home variable
- reinstalled JRE and JDK
- tried Java 7 and 8
- tried Pentaho 5.0, 5.3, 6.0
- tried using JNDI with mysql